# Java p12 Generation from a existing keys

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa

I'm writing a program in Java that generates RSA keys using Crt parameters. I'm able to export the key in a .pem file, but I need to export it in a pkcs12 file. How can I do that in Java?

Comment: Welcome to SO! This isn't a how-to site. If you post attempts you have made to export pkcs12 files other people can help you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java contains native support for PKCS#12 key stores through `KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12")`. However, generally the key stores require you to offer a matching private key / *certificate* pair. Just providing a public key instead of a certificate is not enough. You must create a certificate, for instance a *self signed certificate* to be able to use the PKCS#12 key store provider.

I've tried to create my own `Certificate` instance using an anonymous type, but the PKCS#12 key store only seems to allow X.509 certificates (but it will only tell you when you *store* the key store, i.e. it is not *fail fast*.

---

Here's some code to create the self signed certificate and store the private key and resulting self signed certificate:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.X500Name;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.CertIOException;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509CertificateConverter;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.ContentSigner;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.OperatorCreationException;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentSignerBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex;

public class StoreRSAKeyPairInPKCS12 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // --- generate a key pair (you did this already it seems)
        KeyPairGenerator rsaGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        final KeyPair pair = rsaGen.generateKeyPair();

        // --- create the self signed cert
        Certificate cert = createSelfSigned(pair);

        // --- create a new pkcs12 key store in memory
        KeyStore pkcs12 = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        pkcs12.load(null, null);

        // --- create entry in PKCS12
        pkcs12.setKeyEntry("privatekeyalias", pair.getPrivate(), "entrypassphrase".toCharArray(), new Certificate[] {cert});

        // --- store PKCS#12 as file
        try (FileOutputStream p12 = new FileOutputStream("mystore.p12")) {
            pkcs12.store(p12, "p12passphrase".toCharArray());
        }

        // --- read PKCS#12 as file
        KeyStore testp12 = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        try (FileInputStream p12 = new FileInputStream("mystore.p12")) {
            testp12.load(p12, "p12passphrase".toCharArray());
        }

        // --- retrieve private key
        System.out.println(Hex.toHexString(testp12.getKey("privatekeyalias", "entrypassphrase".toCharArray()).getEncoded()));
    }

    private static X509Certificate createSelfSigned(KeyPair pair) throws OperatorCreationException, CertIOException, CertificateException {
        X500Name dnName = new X500Name("CN=publickeystorageonly");
        BigInteger certSerialNumber = BigInteger.ONE;

        Date startDate = new Date(); // now

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(startDate);
        calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
        Date endDate = calendar.getTime();

        ContentSigner contentSigner = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256WithRSA").build(pair.getPrivate());
        JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder certBuilder = new JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder(dnName, certSerialNumber, startDate, endDate, dnName, pair.getPublic());

        return new JcaX509CertificateConverter().getCertificate(certBuilder.build(contentSigner));
    }

}
```

You will need at least the PKIX library (`bcpkix-jdk15on.jar`) from Bouncy Castle and possibly the library of the Bouncy Castle provider. Installing the Bouncy Castle provider *is not required*.

Comment: My previous answer contained a link to an old answer that created a self signed certificate, but it was very trashy and used an old Bouncy Castle implementation, so I had to refactor code from another answer.

Comment: The other answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43918337/589259).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer it helped me a lot, that's just what I needed ;) ;)

Comment: In openssl I can export p12 file without certificate with the option `-nocerts` is it possible to do it with Java ?