# What is the API for generating self-signed certificates in Java 9-19?

Tags: java, x509certificate, java-11

We have a code that generates self-signed certificate running Java 8 (the api has been removed in java 9). It seems like there will be a new API for generating self-signed certificates starting from JDK 9: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8165481

Is there any example of doing the same as:

```
   class Foo{
     public Foo(){
        CertAndKeyGen keyGen = new CertAndKeyGen("RSA", "SHA256withRSA", null);
        keyGen.generate(2048);
        rootPrivateKey = keyGen.getPrivateKey();
        rootCertificate = keyGen.getSelfCertificate(new X500Name("CN=FooBar"), (long) 24 * 60 * 60);
        CertAndKeyGen subKeyGen =new CertAndKeyGen("RSA","SHA256withRSA",null);
        subKeyGen.generate(2048);
        subPrivateKey = subKeyGen.getPrivateKey();
        subCertificate = subKeyGen.getSelfCertificate(new X500Name("CN=FizzBuzz"), (long) 24 * 60 * 60);

        rootCertificate   = signCertificate(rootCertificate, rootCertificate, rootPrivateKey);
        subCertificate = signCertificate(subCertificate, rootCertificate, rootPrivateKey);

        X509Certificate[] certChain = new X509Certificate[]{subCertificate,rootCertificate};

        KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        store.load(null, null);
        store.setKeyEntry("FizzBuzz Private Key", subPrivateKey, certificatePassword.toCharArray(), certChain);
}

    public X509Certificate signCertificate (X509Certificate inputCertificate, X509Certificate issuerCertificate, PrivateKey issuerPrivateKey)throws Exception {
            X509CertInfo info = new X509CertInfo(inputCertificate.getTBSCertificate());
            info.set(X509CertInfo.ISSUER, issuerCertificate.getSubjectDN());
            X509CertImpl outCert = new X509CertImpl(info);
            outCert.sign(issuerPrivateKey, issuerCertificate.getSigAlgName());
            return outCert;
    }
}
```

in Java 11?

===============**Update**===========

The feature request is here: 
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8058778

Comment: You linked to this question @StephenC

Comment: You provided a link to the same question @StephenC

Comment: Ah, so I did.  I meant this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852290/self-signed-x509-certificate-with-bouncy-castle-in-java

Comment: That is probably a way to  go, but I was wondering if it is possible to do in plain java 11 without using external api/framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use utility classes from OkHttp to achieve this

https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-tls

> A HeldCertificate is a certificate and its private key. Use the builder to create a self-signed certificate that a test server can use for HTTPS:

```
String localhost = InetAddress.getByName("localhost").getCanonicalHostName();
HeldCertificate localhostCertificate = new HeldCertificate.Builder()
    .addSubjectAlternativeName(localhost)
    .build();
```

Comment: My question is how to do it in Java 11 (without using any external lib, framework, etc.)

Comment: The library I linked above is open source, so maybe read through the code and post a working Answer you can self accept.

Answer (score 6):

> It seems like there will be a new API for generating self-signed certificates starting from JDK 9.

I don't think that is true.  The RFE that you linked to was marked as a duplicate of https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8058778.  The latter is **unresolved** as of Java 13 ... meaning that the API that was being proposed still hasn't been incorporated into the Java standard libraries.

Therefore ......

> What is the Java API for generating self-signed certificates in Java 11?

There isn't one.

If you want a practical solution for generating self-signed certs you will need to either use (or copy) third party software, or use `Process` etcetera to drive `keytool`.

Comment: Voted up your answer, and chosen Yuri Schimke's answer since it had a code snippet others can use.

Answer (score 0):

In case an external lib can be used, you can try `bouncycastle` library.

See answers in [Self signed X509 Certificate with Bouncy Castle in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852290/self-signed-x509-certificate-with-bouncy-castle-in-java)