# Create X509 certificate programmactically

Tags: java, kotlin, ssl, quarkus, tls1.3

I would like to create certificates programmatically instead with `java keytool`.

For example, this is how I create a server certificate and would like to translate it into Java code:

```
keytool -v \
        -genkeypair \
        -dname "$SERVER_DN" \
        -keystore "$SERVER_DIR"/keystore.jks \
        -storepass "$SERVER_PW" \
        -keypass "$SERVER_PW" \
        -keyalg "EC" \
        -alias server \
        -validity 1825 \
        -deststoretype pkcs12 \
        -ext KU=digitalSignature,dataEncipherment,keyEncipherment,keyAgreement \
        -ext EKU=serverAuth \
        -ext SAN="$SERVER_SAN"
```

For creating KeyStore I have found the library https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/security/KeyStore.html for creating certificate I have found https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/security/cert/CertificateFactory.html#getInstance(java.lang.String).

I have tried to create a certificate as follows:

```
import io.quarkus.runtime.QuarkusApplication
import io.quarkus.runtime.annotations.QuarkusMain
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory


@QuarkusMain
class Main :QuarkusApplication{
    override fun run(vararg args: String?): Int {
        val cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")
        val cert = cf.generateCertificate(FileInputStream("/Users/developer/jvm/cert-bash/server.crt"))
        return 0
    }
}
```

and got an error

```
2022-06-09 16:30:44,960 ERROR [io.qua.run.Application] (Quarkus Main Thread) Failed to start application (with profile dev): java.io.IOException: Empty input
```

The file is empty and I would like to write the generated certificate into the file.
Do I use `cf.generateCertificate` wrong?

**Update**

As @Edu G suggested the solution on [How to create a X509 certificate using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383898/how-to-create-a-x509-certificate-using-java) I can not find the library sun.security.tools.keytool.* on https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/, why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a X509 certificate using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383898/how-to-create-a-x509-certificate-using-java)

Comment: I could not find the package sun.security.tools.keytool.CertAndKeyGen on https://docs.oracle.com/search/?q=sun.security.tools&pg=1&size=10&product=en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F17&category=en%2Fjava&showfirstpage=true&lang=en. Is sun.security.tools.keytool.CertAndKeyGen not deprecated?

Comment: The names of `CertificateFactory.generate{Certificate,Certificates,CertPath}` are misleading: these do not _create_ the stated things but rather _read them in_ from preexisting data (often a file but may be a database, network connection, or other data source). Out-of-the-box Java does not support creating a cert (with keypair as keytool does, or without). If you can add BouncyCastle, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852290/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930381/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59301937/ and maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925377/